# Loading jdbc driver to connect to MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to connect to my mySQL db with a java program.Im getting a ClassNotFoundException . I copied the mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar file to the java lib folder and set classpath in user variables to the java/lib folder. i used the following statements to establish the connection:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ammy","system","system");
```

Error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
at JDBCEx.main(JDBCEx.java:11)
```

This is what i get when i try to extract the jar file:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin;.
Access is denied
```

Comment: is the jar file is in classpath?

Comment: no this was my classpath: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\lib;. do i have to include the jar file too?

Comment: add the path of MySql ConnecterJ jar file to your classpath

Comment: Is it a web application?

Comment: @NikhilPatil no i was just trying to connect to the database for simple insert and retrieve queries..

Comment: @ChandraSekhar currently im trying this in edit plus.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar i tried changing the classpath to: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin;. it just doesnt work.

Comment: even tried extracting the jar file but it says access denied

Comment: @Ash why are you trying to extract jar. it is not neccessary. classpath should contain mysql jar and rt.jar and current directory

Comment: in my lab we were using oracle database. and the instructor asked me to extract the ojdbc14.jar connector there and then set the Classpath till java\jdk\lib. but i could not download the oracleXe file since i got an error saying it has some malacious code. So then i downloaded the mySql server and trying to establish the connection since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the user variable classpath option, then edit it and add
java/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar to the classpath to make your work done

or download the ConnectorJ  driver from the link

```
http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/
```

and then add that to your classpath. I am using this and it works fine.

Comment: yes i did download it for the and replaced the old jar file with the new one that which i downloaded just now. then closed and re-opened editplus and compiled and ran my program. this is the new error which im getting:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ConnectionUtility

Comment: user variables: CLASSPATH set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar system variables: PATH set to %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Rational\common;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin and JAVA_HOME is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin

Comment: is other programs are running fine?

Comment: no they aren't..im curently trying to execute a simple java program which again shows classNotFoundException.class Demo 
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  System.out.println("Hello World!");
 }
}
This is the program. There must be surely something wrong with my environmental variables.

Comment: would you suggest me to re-install java?

Comment: Go to the classpath and add path of java/lib/rt.jar and path of the mysql jar file separating them with semicolon and lastly add a dot to add current drectory to your classpath. This also should be separated with semicolon And then execute the hello world program through command prompt and reply me

Comment: i suppose this is what you meant: classpath in user variables set toC:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\lib\dt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin;. Its still not working!

Comment: the program's executing finally!! but again im not able to establish the connection to jdbc..still shows ClassNotFoundException

Comment: i did. its giving this error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: is something wrong with the Class.forName() statement i used?

Comment: no this exception will cause only if classpath is not properly configured.

Comment: IDE is not a matter here, if you are a beginer, then I will suggest you to work with edit plus only, because in this case everything should be done by you and you will learn from that. But still if you want to use IDE then Eclipse is seggested.

Answer (score 1):

You have to just put the jar in lib folder.You have to right click on that jar and go in BuilPath and Click on Add to build path.
After your jar works.

Comment: thank you..bt i couldnt find the buildpath option when i right clicked on the jar file

Comment: if you using that tool you can go in lib folder at project and right click and find build path option